# compare between $\sigma(X_1, X_2)$ and $\sigma(X^2_1, X_1 X_2)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

let $X_1, X_2$ be two random variables.

firstly, since $(s, t) \mapsto (s^2, ts)$ is measurable then we can say that $\sigma(X^2_1, X_1 X_2) \subset \sigma(X_1, X_2)$

could we have equality of the two sigma algebras ?

$(s, t) \mapsto (\sqrt{s}, \frac{t}{\sqrt{s}}) $ is continuous for $s > 0$

$X^2_1$ is positive or zero though.

can we conclude anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need not be equal.  For example if $X_1=0$ then the second sigma algebra consists of only the empty set and the whole space.

Another counter-example: take $X_1=I_A-I_{A^{c}}$ and $X_2=0$.